# How to get current keyword name for log trace?

Tags: python, robotframework, keyword

I am using RobotFramework for autotest and need write a keyword to print enough log info, but I cannot find a method to get current keyword name for log trace. Does anyone have any idea how to achieve it? thanks a lot.

Comment: you did not check the report.html of robot framework?

Comment: Hi, as a designer, of course I would check the report.html, but I want write a keyword to display clearly to tester that which keyword got wrong and feedback to designer. for UI test, tester hardly make clear any page element info.

Comment: Since the code you're running has to run from a keyword, why not just hard-code the name of the keyword in your log statements?

Comment: Hi, since some keywords are long and for common use, I hope it act as a input parameter for a log message keyword, if no good solution, I have to use hardcode

Answer (score 5):

There is no support in robot for getting the current keyword name. Since the code you're writing must be run from a keyword, your keyword should know what its own name is.

If you write your keyword in python, the python library can also be a listener which can push and pop keywords on a stack. You can then use that information to format your error message.

Here's a simple example:

```
from robot.libraries.BuiltIn import BuiltIn

class ExampleLibrary(object):
    ROBOT_LISTENER_API_VERSION = 2
    ROBOT_LIBRARY_SCOPE = "GLOBAL"

    def __init__(self):
        self.ROBOT_LIBRARY_LISTENER = self
        self.keywords = []

    def _start_keyword(self, name, attrs):
        self.keywords.append(name)

    def _end_keyword(self, name, attrs):
        self.keywords.pop()

    def log_error_message(self, reason):
        message = "{keyword} failed in testcase {testcase}: {reason}"
        BuiltIn().log(message.format(
            keyword=self.keywords[-2],
            testcase=BuiltIn().get_variable_value("${TEST_NAME}"),
            reason=reason,
        ))
```

Here's an example test case showing how to use it:

```
*** Settings ***
Library  ExampleLibrary.py

*** Keywords ***
A keyword
    log  inside A keyword
    Another keyword

Another keyword
    log error message  something went wrong

*** Test Cases ***
Example
    A keyword
```

When you run the above test, you will get the following in the log:

[image: screenshot of log]